# Basic page layout program from the PrintMaster 2.0 era

Tags: ms-dos, identify-this-software

I remember it as "Fantasy" but the lack of results makes me think I may be wrong.

All I know for sure is that it was a single page layout program; it was contemporary with PrintMaster 2.0, but not as evolved as Bannermania, in terms of UI. That would place it around 1991 as I ran it on a 386SX.

The user was given a large black and white bitmap which mapped to a A4 sheet of paper.

I think there was mouse support.

You could write text, maybe draw lines, maybe stamp predefined patterns; everything was just stored in one bitmap; no history, no high level concepts (no text editing, and so on); I think I used it to make RPG character sheets.

Can you identify this software ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might be thinking of PROSOFT’s “Fontasy”.

https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102625431

https://www.google.com/search?q=fontasy+dos

I saw it in the late ‘80s, maybe even used it briefly, but I don’t remember much about what it could do. I do remember well the clever name. Searching around it appears to have the features you mentioned.

Comment: I used this, a long long time ago...

Comment: Archive.org seems to have a [CGA and Hercules version](https://archive.org/details/prosoft_fontasy_207_for_dos) but it’s download only; not online emulated.

Comment: I haven' t checked yet, but the clever name explains why I was misled, and why search engines were too...

Comment: Thanks, this is the one I was looking for. I ran it, and it doesn't look like it had graphics abilites; I must have used another way, using a combination of a photocopier, scissors, ruler and a pen.....